# DocuSign PDF form field transformation: missing DateSigned

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm using DocuSign REST API CreateEnvelope.

I have a PDF with form fields that I have to upload to DocuSign.

I'm using the PDF form field transformation to transform the PDF fields in to DocuSign tabs and assign them to different signers.

This works fine for Signature and Initial fields but I don't see any DateSigned tab in the document.

Note the names of the PDF form fields match exactly the tabLabel values of the corresponding DocuSign tabs.

Here is the JSON payload:

```
{
    "attachments": [],
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "document": {
                "documentBase64": "...",
                "documentFields": [],
                "documentId": "1",
                "matchBoxes": [],
                "name": "E54.000003631.000009458.0000001.pdf",
                "transformPdfFields": "true"
            },
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "documents": [],
                    "recipients": {
                        "agents": [],
                        "carbonCopies": [],
                        "certifiedDeliveries": [],
                        "editors": [],
                        "inPersonSigners": [],
                        "intermediaries": [],
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "customFields": [],
                                "documentVisibility": [],
                                "email": "[replace this with a valid email]",
                                "excludedDocuments": [],
                                "name": "Recip_2",
                                "recipientAttachments": [],
                                "recipientId": "2",
                                "recipientSignatureProviders": [],
                                "routingOrder": "1",
                                "signingGroupUsers": [],
                                "socialAuthentications": [],
                                "tabs": {
                                    "approveTabs": [],
                                    "checkboxTabs": [],
                                    "companyTabs": [],
                                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "2",
                                            "tabLabel": "S2_DocuSignDateSigned"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "dateTabs": [],
                                    "declineTabs": [],
                                    "emailAddressTabs": [],
                                    "emailTabs": [],
                                    "envelopeIdTabs": [],
                                    "firstNameTabs": [],
                                    "formulaTabs": [],
                                    "fullNameTabs": [],
                                    "initialHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "2",
                                            "tabLabel": "S2_DocuSignInitialHere"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "lastNameTabs": [],
                                    "listTabs": [],
                                    "noteTabs": [],
                                    "numberTabs": [],
                                    "radioGroupTabs": [],
                                    "signerAttachmentTabs": [],
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "2",
                                            "tabLabel": "PdfField_5"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "ssnTabs": [],
                                    "textTabs": [],
                                    "titleTabs": [],
                                    "viewTabs": [],
                                    "zipTabs": []
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "customFields": [],
                                "documentVisibility": [],
                                "email": "[replace this with a valid email]",
                                "excludedDocuments": [],
                                "name": "Recip_1",
                                "recipientAttachments": [],
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "recipientSignatureProviders": [],
                                "signingGroupUsers": [],
                                "socialAuthentications": [],
                                "tabs": {
                                    "approveTabs": [],
                                    "checkboxTabs": [],
                                    "companyTabs": [],
                                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "1",
                                            "tabLabel": "PdfField_3_DocuSignDateSigned"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "dateTabs": [],
                                    "declineTabs": [],
                                    "emailAddressTabs": [],
                                    "emailTabs": [],
                                    "envelopeIdTabs": [],
                                    "firstNameTabs": [],
                                    "formulaTabs": [],
                                    "fullNameTabs": [],
                                    "initialHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "1",
                                            "tabLabel": "PdfField_2_DocuSignInitialHere"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "lastNameTabs": [],
                                    "listTabs": [],
                                    "noteTabs": [],
                                    "numberTabs": [],
                                    "radioGroupTabs": [],
                                    "signerAttachmentTabs": [],
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "1",
                                            "tabLabel": "PdfField_1"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "ssnTabs": [],
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "documentId": "1",
                                            "recipientId": "1",
                                            "tabLabel": "PdfField_4"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "titleTabs": [],
                                    "viewTabs": [],
                                    "zipTabs": []
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "1"
                }
            ],
            "serverTemplates": []
        }
    ],
    "documents": [],
    "emailBlurb": "Please review attached document(s) for electronic signature.",
    "emailSubject": "Please review attached document for electronic signature",
    "recipients": {
        "agents": [],
        "carbonCopies": [],
        "certifiedDeliveries": [],
        "editors": [],
        "inPersonSigners": [],
        "intermediaries": [],
        "signers": []
    },
    "status": "sent",
    "templateRoles": []
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong.

The initial PDF (generated by our produced) contained only PDF fields of type Signature.

We have updated the PDF generation to have:

- PDF fields of type Signature for the SignHere and InitialHere DocuSign tabs
- PDF fields of type Text  for the DateSigned and Text DocuSign tabs

Now all PDF Fields are correctly converted and the corresponding DocuSign tab is added to the document.

Comment: ***Thank you*** for posting the answer!